# Can our eyes and ears detect phase information in addition to amplitude and frequency information?

Tags: visible-light, waves, biophysics, vision

Both eyes and ears detect continuous waves that impinge upon them - electromagnetic waves in the case of eyes, and sound air pressure waves in the case of ears. The amplitude of these waves is interpreted as brightness in the case of eyes and loudness in the case of ears, and the frequency is interpreted as color in the case of eyes and pitch in the case of ears.

In both cases, if the impinging wave is given by $f(t)$ via $f(t) := E_x(t)$ or $f(t) := P(t)$ respectively, then all the obviously detectable information seems to be captured by the spectral power function $I(\omega) := |\tilde{f}(\omega)|^2$, where $\tilde{f}(\omega) := \int dt\ \ f(t)\, e^{-i \omega t}$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)$. Can our eyes or ears detect any information contained in the Fourier transform's phase as well? (When the Fourier transform is used in image processing, the phase information is actually usually [far more important](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1456290/) than the amplitude information, but of course the waves that typically impinge upon our eyes and ears may behave very differently from typical image data.)

Presumably they can't detect any difference between two incident waves $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ with $\tilde{f}(\omega) \equiv e^{-i \omega T} \tilde{g}(\omega)$ for any constant $T$, because this simply corresponds to shifting the time $t = 0$ by $T$ - so our eyes and ears would need to use some kind of internal clock that breaks time-translational invariance, which they presumably do not have, as a reference in order to distinguish them.

But can they distinguish, say, the difference between two signals
$$f(t) = A_1 \cos (\omega_1 t) + A_2 \cos(\omega_2 t - \Delta_f)$$
and
$$g(t) = A_1 \cos (\omega_1 t) + A_2 \cos(\omega_2 t - \Delta_g)$$
with $\Delta_f \neq \Delta_g$? In this case
$$\tilde{f}(\omega) = \pi \left[ A_1 \left( \delta(\omega - \omega_1) + \delta(\omega - \omega_1) \right) + A_2 \left( e^{-i \Delta_f} \delta(\omega - \omega_2) + e^{i \Delta_f} \delta(\omega + \omega_2) \right) \right]$$
while
$$\tilde{g}(\omega) = \pi \left[ A_1 \left( \delta(\omega - \omega_1) + \delta(\omega - \omega_1) \right) + A_2 \left( e^{-i \Delta_g} \delta(\omega - \omega_2) + e^{i \Delta_g} \delta(\omega + \omega_2) \right) \right]$$
In general the two signals look completely different when plotted as a function of time, but they both have the same power spectrum
$$ I(\omega) = \pi^2 \left[ A_1^2\, \delta(\omega - \omega_1) + A_2^2\, \delta(\omega - \omega_2) + (\omega \to -\omega) \right]$$
(where we've used a common abuse of notation by pretending that $\delta(x)^2 = \delta(x)$, which is not legitimate in the true continuum case, but is if the frequencies are finely discretized and the delta functions really represent Kronecker deltas). Can our eyes see or ears hear any difference between these two signals?

(To preempt the inevitable comment that this question would be more appropriate for Biology Stack Exchange: I disagree. I think that physicists are probably better able to answer this question than biologists, because they are most used to thinking of waves in these terms.)

Comment: Possibly related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277493/can-human-ear-distinguish-between-sounds-of-different-phase.

Comment: And also this, but only regards the  auditory aspect http://www.audioholics.com/room-acoustics/human-hearing-phase-distortion-audibility-part-2

Comment: The wavelength of visible light is ~500nm: you would have to hold your eyes stationary to within ~ a wavelength to see any phase information in light.  So, no, you can't.

Comment: @tfb Wouldn't the same logic imply that you can't see any frequency information in light either?

Comment: @tparker No.  You don't detect frequency by having something that counts cycles, you do it by having materials in your eye which are sensitive to photons of various energies.  This has as little to do with phase as the photochemistry of film does, for instance.

Comment: @tfb But the energy-time uncertainty relation in quantum mechanics means that something can only have a well-defined energy if you measure it over a long enough time period to count several cycles.

Comment: @tparker That's  of the (minor) reasons why your eyes have a rather broad response to colours, yes.

Comment: @tfb Citation? Also, why can't you hold you eyes stationary to within one wavelength? You only need to do so for a few oscillations, which seems easily possible.

Comment: The citation is in your comment: if the eye is to detect anything in a finite time then there is frequency (colour) uncertainty, which limits how well it can do.  In practice this is very far from the limit since the eye doesn't even attempt to detect single frequencies.  As to the rest, just look at the retina: does it look like a system for making phase-accurate measurements of radiation with wavelengths of half a micron?  Short of invoking magic I think it is safe to assume that we do not detect phase information in light because there is no mechanism to do so.